# JavaScript - update element innerHTML every n seconds

Tags: javascript

With the JsFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/MeetJoeBlack/jabwtpd0/), I need to change the innerHTML for a div every 1s with a value from an array of 100 elements sequentially. I'm using a loop to iterate through the elements of the array, then using `setTimeout` to update the innerHTML for `#number`every 1000ms. However what I see is that the element is getting updated at once after 1000ms.

```
let num = 100
let data = [];

for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
  data.push(Math.random() * 100);
}
console.log(data);

function loadScript(){
    console.log(`Calling loadScript`);
    let elm = document.getElementById("number");
    for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
     setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(`Setting innerHTML as ${data[i]}`);
        elm.innerHTML = data[i].toString();
     },1000);
  }
}

loadScript();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The loop sets the timeout for all items to be 1000ms, and they all execute at this time. A simple solution would be to multiply the timeout with `i`:

```
 setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(`Setting innerHTML as ${data[i]}`);
    elm.innerHTML = data[i].toString();
 }, i * 1000);
```

```js
const colorsRainbow = ["rgb(120,28,129)","rgb(64,67,153)","rgb(72,139,194)","rgb(107,178,140)","rgb(159,190,87)","rgb(210,179,63)","rgb(231,126,49)","rgb(217,33,32)"];
let num = 100
let data = [];

for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
  data.push(Math.random() * 100);
}
console.log(data);

let elm = document.getElementById("number");

function loadScript(){
 console.log(`Calling loadScript`);
 for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
     setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(`Setting innerHTML as ${data[i]}`);
       elm.innerHTML = data[i].toString();
     }, i * 1000);
  }
}

loadScript();
```

```html
<div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 500px;">
  <h1>Color Changer</h1>
  <div id="number"></div>
</div>
```

However, the 1st solution creates one timer for each element of the array at once. A better solution would be to create one timer, and when it's done create another one:

```
function loadScript() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(`Setting innerHTML as ${data[i]}`);
    elm.innerHTML = data[i].toString();

    // increment i, and if i is less then the data length, call loadScript() again
    ++i < data.length && loadScript();
  }, 1000);
}
```

```js
const colorsRainbow = ["rgb(120,28,129)","rgb(64,67,153)","rgb(72,139,194)","rgb(107,178,140)","rgb(159,190,87)","rgb(210,179,63)","rgb(231,126,49)","rgb(217,33,32)"];

let num = 100
let data = [];

for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
  data.push(Math.random() * 100);
}
console.log(data);

let elm = document.getElementById("number");
let i = 0;

function loadScript() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(`Setting innerHTML as ${data[i]}`);
    elm.innerHTML = data[i].toString();

    // increment i, and if i is less then the data length, call loadScript() again
    ++i < data.length && loadScript(); 
  }, 1000);
}

loadScript();
```

```html
<div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 500px;">
  <h1>Color Changer</h1>
  <div id="number"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good thing you added the re-timeout. I was about to submit that as answer ;)

Comment: It may be prudent to add an if for wrapping the index value back to 0, or this will be a train wreck when i == 100

Comment: It won't . `++i < data.length && loadScript();` increments `i` before comparing it to the `data.length`, so if `i === 100`, it won't call `loadScript()` again.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version using setInterval instead of setTimeout. I find setInterval is a little cleaner than chaining setTimeout calls.

```
function loadScript() {
  console.log(`Calling loadScript`);
  let elm = document.getElementById("number");
  let i = 0;
  var intervalId = setInterval(() => {
    console.log(`Setting innerHTML as ${data[i]}`);
    elm.innerHTML = data[i].toString();
    i++;
    if (i === data.length) {
      console.log('done');
      clearInterval(intervalId);
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```